# Android studio camera2 eliminate noise

Tags: android, image-processing

I am working with camera in android studio and i have YUV420_888 as output from camera2 via ImageReader. Problem is that i got this strange noise, or whatever it is called. Here is [link](https://s21.postimg.org/8wg5a6jef/Screenshot_2016_08_31_18_12_48.png) to a picture. If you look close there are 6-7 circles with different shades of gray. I use only Y channel because i need black and white image and Y channel is exactly that. It is big problem because its interfering with the edge detection algorithm and those "circles" are represented as noise in edge detection. Also they only appear when the surface is plane white. Can anyone tell me why this happen and how to fix it?

EDIT:
So i found out that its something about the code. This is original application where i tried to get camera2 working.

package com.example.nikola.camera2project;

```
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureResult;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "AndroidCameraApi";
    private TextureView textureView;
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }
    private String cameraId;
    protected CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    protected CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    protected CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private Size imageDimension;
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    private File file;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;

    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
        assert textureView != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(640, 480, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 1);




    }


    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            //open your camera here
            openCamera();
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            // Transform you image captured size according to the surface width and height
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        }
    };



    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            //This is called when the camera is open
            Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();

        }
        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
    };
    protected void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }
    protected void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected void createCameraPreview() {
        try {
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
             captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
           cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    //The camera is already closed
                    if (null == cameraDevice) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);


        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        Log.e(TAG, "is camera open");
        try {
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "openCamera X");
    }
    protected void updatePreview() {
        if(null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
        }
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void closeCamera() {
        if (null != cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != imageReader) {
            imageReader.close();
            imageReader = null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // close the app
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!!!, you can't use this app without granting permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
        startBackgroundThread();
        if (textureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera();
        } else {
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onPause");
        //closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Because i needed to do some working around frames this is change i made

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        assert surfaceView != null;
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(480,640, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888,10);
}

private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            //This is called when the camera is open
            Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
            mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    Image image =  reader.acquireLatestImage();
                    if(image != null) {
                        ByteBuffer buffer0 = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] Y = new byte[buffer0.remaining()];
                        buffer0.get(Y);

                        //I do work here but this is for preview grayscale only

                        byte[] Bits = new byte[Y.length * 4]; //That's where the RGBA array goes.

                        for (int i = 0; i < Y.length; i++) {
                            Bits[i * 4] =
                                    Bits[i * 4 + 1] =
                                            Bits[i * 4 + 2] = Y[i];
                            Bits[i * 4 + 3] = -1;//0xff, that's the alpha.
                        }

                        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(Bits));
                        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, (int) (surfaceView.getHeight() * 1.33333), surfaceView.getHeight(), true);
                        Canvas c;
                        c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                        c.drawBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, null);
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                        image.close();



                    }

                }
            },mBackgroundHandler);



        }

 protected void createCameraPreview() {
        try {

            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(mImageReader.getSurface()), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    //The camera is already closed
                    if (null == cameraDevice) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And the rest is the same. When i display this i get what you can see on picture, but in first program when i directly display YUV420_888 on TextureView like in first program, everything is OK, but when i do this changes i got those noise. Any idea why?

EDIT 2:
Whole code :

```
package com.example.nikola.camera2project;


import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureResult;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "AndroidCameraApi";
    private TextureView textureView;
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }
    private String cameraId;
    protected CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    protected CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    protected CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private Size imageDimension;
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    private File file;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;

    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        assert surfaceView != null;
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(480,640, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888,10);




    }



    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            //This is called when the camera is open
            Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
            imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    Image image =  reader.acquireLatestImage();
                    if(image != null) {
                        ByteBuffer buffer0 = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] Y = new byte[buffer0.remaining()];
                        buffer0.get(Y);
                        byte[] Bits = new byte[Y.length * 4]; //That's where the RGBA array goes.
                        for (int i = 0; i < Y.length; i++) {
                            Bits[i * 4] =
                                    Bits[i * 4 + 1] =
                                            Bits[i * 4 + 2] = Y[i];
                            Bits[i * 4 + 3] = -1;//0xff, that's the alpha.
                        }
                        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(Bits));
                        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, (int) (surfaceView.getHeight() * 1.33333), surfaceView.getHeight(), true);
                        Canvas c;
                        c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                        c.drawBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, null);
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                        image.close();



                    }

                }
            },mBackgroundHandler);

        }
        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
    };
    protected void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }
    protected void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected void createCameraPreview() {
        try {
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
             captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());
           cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(imageReader.getSurface()), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    //The camera is already closed
                    if (null == cameraDevice) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);


        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        Log.e(TAG, "is camera open");
        try {
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "openCamera X");
    }
    protected void updatePreview() {
        if(null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
        }
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // close the app
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!!!, you can't use this app without granting permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
        startBackgroundThread();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onPause");
        //closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }




    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        openCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be quantization noise due to the hardware limitations of your camera. If a surface is dimly lit, the camera may use automatic brightness adjustment and/or white balance to make the scene more presentable. If the camera does not have an adjustable aperture, adjustable shutter, or high-resolution ADCs, it would do the adjustment digitally, e.g., by multiplying the "Y" value by an integer coefficient (for each pixel). Thus, quantization noise.

You may obtain better results by adjusting the [AWB mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_AWB_MODE). Better lighting may help. Or, you could adjust the thresholds in your edge detection algorithm.

**EDIT**

Add a call to `surfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888)` immediately after your `addCallback()` call.

Turns out this was actually a result of the surface's default internal format, which was something smaller than ARGB_8888. Happened on an S6 as well.

Comment: I tried to change AWB mode but it doesn't help. I tried this code only on my phone (Samsung galaxy S2 with CM12 mode). Also when i open my app for camera the picture is much better. My code is similar to this one if it can help. The problem about edges is that edge i want to follow is have the same derivative as those circles. http://inducesmile.com/android/android-camera2-api-example-tutorial/

Comment: You should definitely be able to get the same quality from your own software as you do from the camera app. Looking at the bytes in your image file, there is definitely quantization going on, but it's not clear why. I would've expected YUV420_888 to look pretty good, but maybe the capture pipeline had to do some conversions to get you there, and some information was lost. I would try the other available formats. You may not be able to run your edge-detection algorithm on them, but you can at least see how they look on the TextureView.

Comment: Actually it seems i did something wrong with the program but cant get what. I will edit my original post to add some code

Comment: This is an older device... if you were somehow getting a surface in RGB565 format, that would explain the quantization in the image file, which is right around 3 bits, but that's just a guess. Have you tried checking the values in plane 0, above, to see if they're quantized? At least that would tell you if it's before or after your code.

Comment: I just tested it and if i am right it is not quantized, and i am not doing anything with image i got, just make it Bitmap and preview on surfaceView. I am new to image processing, and what i have read it should be low numbers and some zeros, but i look for about 200 pixels and its from -127 to 127 and there is not some place where all are zeros etc. If i get the term quantized right its all right. But still dont know why this happens. Would it help if i place the whole code here?

Comment: The values should take up most of the range -128 to 127. 0 corresponds to black, 127 (and -128) would be a mid-level gray, and -1 would be full white (the display hardware treats them as unsigned). If the data were quantized, only certain values in that range would show up, like in increments of 8; 0, 8, 16, 24, etc. If not, then any value in the range should be game. I don't need to see more code at this time; I don't think it's your math that's doing this.

Comment: Than its not here is some pixels copied from the android studio when i do debug. There are -42,-43,-44,-45 so its not quantized.
0 = 0
1 = -49
2 = -49
3 = -51
4 = -47
5 = -47
6 = -47
7 = -47
8 = -47
9 = -45
10 = -44
11 = -44
12 = -43
13 = -43
14 = -42
15 = -46
16 = -43
17 = -43
18 = -44
19 = -45
20 = -43
21 = -46
22 = -45
23 = -43
24 = -44
25 = -44
26 = -42
27 = -43
28 = -42
29 = -41
30 = -45

Comment: OK now I would like to see some more code --  b/c if your algorithm is operating on the data you just posted (which isn't quantized, which implies the circles are not present), then I don't see how you could be detecting the circles.

Comment: I made EDIT2 in original post. When i preview like that i see those circles without any processing. But they appear only when i look at plain white surface like wall or paper

Comment: Actually, I wanted to see the processing you were doing, and where you were doing it, so I can verify it's on the plane 0 data. Since you mentioned it, though, maybe we can learn something about the circles based on how they become apparent on screen. 1. Are you sure they are completely absent on non-white surfaces, vs. just not being able to see them? 2. When panning from a non-white surface to a white surface, do the circles appear instanteously, or does it take them a second? Or, do they simply end abruptly at the boundary of the white surface? Please be detailed in your response.

Comment: I am positive that it doesn't appear when its other color. And here is how moving from my table to wall affects circles. I did screenshot so you must look closely on wall, on third picture circles appear. I have red-green daltonism but i think i can see the difference between scales of gray, this is at least black and white. Here are pictures, and about timing when i move phone so there is a lot of white surface it starts immediately, and when it changes lightness circles start to appear.

Comment: Here are [link1](https://postimg.org/image/l4rm7jiud/) and [link2](https://postimg.org/image/g7e1mfgv9/) without circles, and when there is more white it starts to [appear](https://postimg.org/image/4jjzrvrqd/)

Comment: OK I ran your code and changed my answer. All your pictures were quantized, by the way -- it only became perceptible (as circles) when you were viewing a smooth surface with a shallow brightness gradient.